# OneNote to open link in Chrome without Chrome being default

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink, onenote

I have a very simple question I could not find answer for myself: I want links in OneNote to open in Chrome.
Note that the default browser is IE and I cannot change it (not admin etc).

Tried: "chrome_path url" - didn't work. Everything I could think about didn't work.

Please provide explicit solution so that link from within OneNote opens in Chrome rather than in IE.
To note, there are multiple links, so batch file won't do in this case. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a little go with testing some ideas that I had though I'm very new to OneNote. It's easy enough to open Chrome from a hyperlink:

- Select text to link
- Add link
- Select the file icon and navigate to chrome.exe. In my instance - C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

I believe you cannot pass arguments to the exe as it is considered a security issue. This certainly used to be the case and I'm not sure if they have modified their thinking since. The only way I can think of is to create a batch file which includes your ideal website and link to the batch file:

"start chrome http://www.youtube.com"

Comment: hi antony. i did the same investigative work you did with onenote prior to asking for help, although not new with onenote at all. batch will not do, because i have plenty of links, which means I will have to create 50 different batch files, while all i wanted was to open all onenote links with chrome, while ie being a default browser (which i have no control over). so, sorry, cannot accept your answer as it doesn't answer my question. its not how to open chrome from hyperlink, but how to open hyperlink in chrome under conditions described. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to do it, though neither is the perfect:

1. There is a [3rd party OneNote add-on](https://www.onenotegem.com/document/how-to-choose-browser-edge-chrome-firefox-ie-to-open-link-in-onenote) which adds more browsers in the right-click menu. Though it is not free and maybe can't be installed on restricted computers.
2. It works only on OneNote docs which are saved onto Onedrive. Open the OneNote page which has the links right in the Chrome, not in the desktop app. Then any links you click will open in the same browser. You can get the address of the OneNote page by clicking on 'Copy Link to Page' in OneNote app, then paste it to a notepad. Copy the first url to Chrome's address bar.

Comment: solution 1: you are right cannot be installed on restricted computer, otherwise i'd change registry instead. 2: copying link to page i knew, but didn't know you can open in chrome, can you detail the last sentence ("first url") cause did't work for me. thanks!

Comment: So, when you paste the 'Copy Link to Page' into a Notepad, you got something like this: `https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx/Documents/otapi?cid=c443994ab1f99579&id=documents&wd=target%28Quick%20Notes.one%7C9AFB3169-2746-7C44-B235-956EDB5B8234%2F%29
onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/c443994ab1f99579/Documents/otapi/Quick%20Notes.one#section-id={9AFB3169-2746-7C44-B235-956EDB5B8234}&end`. Copy only the first url, e.g. `https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx/Documents/otapi?cid=c443994ab1f99579&id=documents&wd=target%28Quick%20Notes.one%7C9AFB3169-2746-7C44-B235-956EDB5B8234%2F%29` to Chrome.

Comment: I just found it works only if the OneNote is saved to Onedrive. It gives only the onenote url if it is saved on a local disk.

Comment: not only that, but also if live.com is blocked from access .... well thanks for exploration, tried all kind of things, cannot find an easy way to do such trivial thing.

Answer (score -1):

For those who has admin right, this problem can be solved by following [Make Chrome your default browser](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95417?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). It is set at machine level, not onenote level.

Comment: well, the premise of the question : no admin rights (laptop from work)